# rounding problems of decimal values with DbDataAdapter Update

Tags: c#, sql

We are having problems with the OleDbDataAdapter.Update method. We pass in a dataset with a column in it of type decimal(18,2) . When I pass the value 1.225 the value stored is 1.22
Using SQL Profiler i also see that the update statement is something like:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [Table] ([Id], [DecimalValue]) VALUES (@P1, @P2), 1, 1.22
```

So somewhere along the line the value is cut off.

When I try to execute a sql statement directly:

```
update [Table] set [DecimalValue] = 1.229 where Id = 1
```

The stored value is 1.23 which is what we want.

Is there any way to control the rounding of decimal values in the OleDbDataAdapter?

Comment: Have you debugged your C# code to confirm that you're passing 1.225 to the `Update` method?

Comment: Yes, the data visualizer shows 1.229 in the dataset